# The lightning almost snatches away their sight. What does this sentence mean?

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-al-baqarah

From Surah Baqarah verse 2:20, I don't understand the grammatical meaning or the example Allah is giving as a metaphor?

> "The lightning almost snatches away their sight. Every time it lights [the way] for them, they walk therein; but when darkness comes over them, they stand [still]. And if Allah had willed, He could have taken away their hearing and their sight. Indeed, Allah is over all things competent."
>
> <sup>[Quran 2:20](https://quran.com/2/20)</sup>

Comment: text in heading is not in the cite in text

Comment: now edited please help

Comment: have not your ever looked at welding ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welding ) ?

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_blindness . Cite:

> Flash blindness is visual impairment during and following exposure to a light flash of extremely high intensity.[1] It may last for a few seconds to a few minutes.

Comment: OWW yea wielding........ well never imagined lighting that way....

Answer (score -1):

> **يَكَادُ الۡبَرۡقُ يَخۡطَفُ اَبۡصَارَهُمۡ​ؕ كُلَّمَاۤ اَضَآءَ لَهُمۡ مَّشَوۡا فِيۡهِۙ وَاِذَاۤ اَظۡلَمَ عَلَيۡهِمۡ قَامُوۡا**​ؕ
>
> Every time it lights [the way] for them, they walk therein; but when darkness comes over them, they stand [still].

It refers to those *hypocrites* who disbelieved completely but had become Muslims merely, to further their *worldly interests*. The second parable refers to those who were prone to *doubt and hesitation* or whose *faith was weak*; who believed in the Truth but not to the extent of exposing themselves to hardships for its sake.

They move a little ahead when circumstances seem favourable, but when either difficulties cloud the horizon, or when they are given directives which run counter to their desires or inherited prejudices, they are seized with alarm and come to a halt.

[Reference,](http://www.alqayim.net/en/artical/31/d-1074)

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Please help me, I aked them meanin of the phrase "The lightning almost snatches away their sight."

Comment: Al right,  i will edit it for you.